# Automatically Account for 1.csv through 3000.csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to get this Python program to run through 3000 csv files, each titled 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv, all the way through 3000.csv. How can I do this by just handling the names, without using something like glob, or os.listdir. Here's how the code looks:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import csv
import os

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

header_keys = []
for n, fName in enumerate(['3.csv','4.csv','5.csv','6.csv','7.csv','8.csv','9.csv','10.csv','11.csv','12.csv',]):
with open(fName) as fh:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(fh, fieldnames=['header', 'data'], delimiter=',')
    if n == 0:
        for values in csv_reader:
```

What do I change the part inside the "enumerate" with (the '3.csv', '4.csv', etc.)? Is there any way I can just tell it "files numbered 1.csv through 3000.csv"?

Answer (score 1):

```
for n, fn in enumerate(range(1,3001)):
  with open('{0}.csv'.format(fn)) as fh:
```

Since your csv files names are just the numbers from 1 to 3000, just iterate from the range and create a new string that becomes `#.csv` using [string formatter to make it easier](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). I think you wanted your `with` stuff and below indented one over so it's within the large for loop.